# Error on Python defined function call

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

When I define a path to a subset of data that tries to join the files found in that folder:

```
subset_path='c:\data\grant\files'
subset_data_path=os.path.join(subset_path,'SubsetFiles')
```

I get an error on the "os.path.join" function which states that "NameError: name 'os' is not defined."

Note that I have imported the 'os' module and many other operating modules such as 'subprocess,' 'sys' and so on.

Any suggestions about what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the os module?

```
import os
subset_path='c:\data\grant\files'
subset_data_path=os.path.join(subset_path,'SubsetFiles')
```

Comment: Yup. And that is so stated in my query.

Comment: are you working in an virtualenv or something? Because I get exact that error, you have only, if skip the import line.

Comment: To your point, Beowulf, I'm using Python on the Ananconda3 platform. Maybe if I switch to a pure Python platform, that will clear it up. Otherwise, I don't understand the rest of your question re "skip the import line."

Comment: If I run the code without the import statement, then I get the name-error - that was meant with "skip the import line". You should consider adding tags for your anaconda version, as it seems the installation misses the os-module.

Comment: Tags? Sorry, I don't know what this means in Python. Is that the same thing as a comment?

Comment: No, tags on your stackoverflow question, so that others know, the question is about an anaconda context. I did this already for you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Beowulf was correct. The error was a function of the platform and moving to a Python27 environment, not Anaconda3, solved this problem. Now, I have to figure out why my python scripts are working only on a line by line basis and not when I "import" them in toto.